# How do I do this CSS border-bottom

Tags: html, css

How do I do a CSS Border-bottom that looks like this?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBbXC.png]

you can see it on the internet here: http://themes.laborator.co/neon/frontend/main/

This is what I've got so far

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK2M0.png]

but I want it to look exactly how they did it! Please advise, this is the CSS I did to get what I have so far.

```
.active {
color: #ff4e50;
border-bottom: 5px solid #ff4e50;

}
```

What I am specifically asking is how do I make it touch closely like they did, and change it so that it is as wide as the text. I tried inspect element but could not find it

==
ALL MY CURRENT CODE: LIVE PREVIEW + LIVE EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/FLq5c/3/

HTML:
    
      
        
          example company

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.customnav {
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 13px;
line-height:20px;

}

.customnav li {
color: blue;

}

.header {

font-size: 28px;

}

.active {
color: #ff4e50;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ff4e50;
line-height: 20px;



}

.active a, .active a:hover {
color: #ff4e50;
}
```

Comment: You’ll have to show us your HTML code (relevant parts only!), and what other CSS is applied to them as well. Your border currently being wider than the text might be due to padding on the element you’re applying it to – that would have to go for the desired effect, of course.

Comment: hey I've added the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set a line height or height :

```
.active {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ff4e50;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ff4e50;
}
```

I've updated the demo with your html and css [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FLq5c/4/)

Comment: Could you update your question with the css and html you are using ? I tell you why it isn't working but I need something to work with.

Comment: KK I've added the HTML as well as the CSS for the overall menubar

Comment: hey thanks so much for your help so far! I'm having a little bit of an issue, from your demo I've copied things in to get mine to work. It is working better now but it is not exactly the right thing. Please advise here is an image: http://i.imgur.com/ToiHU4b.png and I've added the current CSS for that to the main post

Comment: Change the `padding` to `margin` so the `border` is the same size as the text. That sould do it !

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. that didn't actually work. changing just the padding-bottom to margin-bottom does this: http://imgur.com/Fd8nlVx and changing both padding-top and padding-bottom to margin-top and margin-bottom does this: http://imgur.com/k368Iy0  please advise!

Comment: I was talking about the padding to the left and right, if there is none, you need to reduce the width of the element which has the border. If necessary add a left and right margin after to separate the menu items.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite sure I follow! I'm using bootstrap, how should I implement the code you sent in the menu demo? I think that would be the best way. Thank you so much I appreciate your help a lot. Perhaps if you edited your demo so that it used bootstrap?

Comment: Hey, ignore that. I've added bootstrap, all of my HTML and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/FLq5c/2/ - its on that site that lets u edit the code in real time that you sent me, so that the edit you make will work for me! Since its my exact code! Many Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that! And sorry for wasting your time :( ! Correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/FLq5c/3/

Comment: Update answer with your html and css.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Just one last thing, if you are able to help me with it, how do I make it so that the rest have a faded underline like at this site: http://forum.webflow.com/ - the inactive ones have a faded border - bottom. please advise. Plus also how can I reduce the gap between the text and the border so that it looks more like the effect I was trying to get

Comment: If I answered you question correctly could you update it as such and ask another question with the new details and I will be glad to help you.

Comment: KK. The last thing to finish this question up and then I can move onto another is to reduce the gap between the text and the border-bottom so it looks like the effect I was trying to get. At the moment it is not close enough. Thanks - the current demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FLq5c/4/

Comment: Hey Thanks! This one is all solved, could you please check out my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180664/fix-border-bottom-menu  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They use a `pseudo` element to create the border effect. If you inspect the element using Chrome Development Tools you can see that there is an `::after` element inside the `span` child of the menu item that contains the relevant CSS that you are interested in.

The way they are doing it is something like this:

```
.active {
    color: #ff4e50;
    position: relative;
}

.active::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Play around with the `bottom`, `left`, and `right` values until you get it right for your specific layout.

Comment: hey, sorry I don't really understand that pseudo stuff. Could you direct me as to where I can find that CSS?