# Fix border-bottom menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my menu: http://jsfiddle.net/FLq5c/8/

That is a link that takes you to one of those online code editors, so that you can send me the updated link with the correct code.

The issue I have is that, as well as the "Active" page being in red, the border-bottom of it needs to be red too. And the rest of the border-bottoms need to be green.

I tried to achieve this using

```
.customnav .nav > li {
    color: blue;
    margin: 12px 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.active {
    color: #ff4e50;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e50;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

But that does not work. It makes ALL of the border-bottoms grey. Please advise, please check the jsfiddle link and update the code there and send me the updated link. You can see the full HTML and CSS over there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.active` selector is less precise than `.customnav .nav > li`, which mean the `.active` selector is overridden by the other one (`.customnav .nav > li`).

Possible solutions :

```
.customnav .nav > li.active {
    color: #ff4e50;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e50;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

or adding `!important` to the the property :

```
.active {
    color: #ff4e50;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e50 !important;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/FLq5c/10/)**, This works.

```
.customnav .nav > li {
    color: blue;
    margin: 12px 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

.customnav .nav li.active {
    color: #ff4e50;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e50 !important;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

The reason it didn't work was that, `border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);` means it is black with opacity of 10%;

And the reason why `.active` couldn't alone get your border red was that css relies on priority. And In css `.customnav .nav li.active` will get more priority than just `.active` on the same element or even `li.active`

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
.customnav .nav > li.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff4e50;
}
```